# copy, paste, transpose rows with pictures

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that copies and pastes rows from input sheet to output sheet. I find PRODUCT NAME and END DATE, then copy the whole row and transpose when pasting it. I am using transpose because I want to have vertical table.

I have a problem with images because I don't know how to copy them to proper cell so they match with Name and Date. I've managed to write a script that is copying and pasting images but it puts all of them in cell A1. When I want to add range to `target_sheet.Paste` I am getting `vba method intersect of object _application failed` error.

Below you can see how input and output sheets look.

Input sheet:

[image]

Expected output sheet (with only 3 columns) :

[image]

It is very important to know that 'input' sheet contains many products with names, prices and images and there is always a blank row between them. The number of images in each row can be different (from 1 to 25).

```
Sub copy_paste()

Dim Cell As Range
Dim src_rng As String
Dim LR As Long
Dim source_sheet As Worksheet
Dim target_sheet As Worksheet
Dim pic As Shape

'worksheet with source data
Set source_sheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("input")
'worksheet with newly created template
Set target_sheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("output")

'range of cells I want to check
src_rng = "A14:A26"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

target_sheet.Cells.Delete
    'copy paste, transpose product line rows
    For Each Cell In source_sheet.Range(src_rng)
    LR = target_sheet.Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        If Cell.Value = "Name" Then
            Cell.EntireRow.Copy
            target_sheet.Range("A" & LR).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
        End If
    Next
    
    'copy paste, transpose end line rows
    For Each Cell In source_sheet.Range(src_rng)
        LR = target_sheet.Range("B10000").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        If Cell.Value = "Date" Then
            Cell.EntireRow.Copy
            target_sheet.Range("B" & LR).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
        End If
    Next
    
    'copy paste image
    For Each Cell In source_sheet.Range(src_rng)
        LR = target_sheet.Range("C10000").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        If Cell.Value = "Image" Then
            For Each pic In source_sheet.Shapes
                If Not Application.Intersect(pic.TopLeftCell, Range(src_rng)) Is Nothing Then
                    pic.CopyPicture
                    target_sheet.Paste
                End If
            Next pic
        End If
    Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Does your existing code correctly what you want, except the part commented as `'copy paste image`? I mean, do the resulted cells size satisfy you?

Comment: @FaneDuru yes, I just have a problem with transposing images from rows in 'input' sheet into column C in 'output' sheet

Comment: You must try creating an equivalence array between the existing pictures `TopLeftCell` address and the cell where they should be transposed. Then, all pictures existing in the array will be copied and placed according to the equivalent cell `Top` and `Left` properties.

Comment: But I cannot believe that the format of the pasted range will have the necessary space to properly keep the shape in its size limits... Copying the range in that way will  not keep the cells existing size.

Answer (score 1):

Please, try the next code. It follows the logic deduced from your last question edit, respectively: the former "Name" becomes "Product Name", "Date" becomes "End Date" and the row keeping the pictures is the one below "Product Name" row. **It is able to process  two or three product names/pictures per group**:

```
Sub copy_paste()
 Dim Cell As Range, src_rng As String, LR As Long
 Dim source_sheet As Worksheet, target_sheet As Worksheet
 Dim pic As Shape, arrPAddr, rngTr As Range, k As Long
 Dim cellRHeight As Range, nrShapesPerRange As Long 'to be 2 or 3

 nrShapesPerRange = 2 'Choose here initial number of shapes per row (2 or 3)
 'worksheet with source data
 Set source_sheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("input")
 'worksheet with newly created template
 Set target_sheet =  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("output")

 'range of cells I want to check
 src_rng = "A14:A26"
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ReDim arrPAddr(1 To 2, 1 To source_sheet.Shapes.count): k = 1
    target_sheet.cells.Delete: For Each pic In target_sheet.Shapes: pic.Delete: Next
    'copy paste, transpose product line rows
    For Each Cell In source_sheet.Range(src_rng)
        LR = target_sheet.Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row + 1
        If Cell.value = "Product Name" Then
            source_sheet.Range(Cell.Offset(, 1), Cell.Offset(, 3)).Copy
            Set rngTr = target_sheet.Range("A" & LR)
            rngTr.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlAll, Transpose:=True
            arrPAddr(1, k) = Cell.Offset(1, 1).Address
            arrPAddr(2, k) = rngTr.Offset(, 2).Address: k = k + 1
            arrPAddr(1, k) = Cell.Offset(1, 2).Address
            arrPAddr(2, k) = rngTr.Offset(1, 2).Address: k = k + 1
            If nrShapesPerRange = 3 Then
                arrPAddr(1, k) = Cell.Offset(1, 3).Address
                arrPAddr(2, k) = rngTr.Offset(2, 2).Address: k = k + 1
            End If
            If cellRHeight Is Nothing Then Set cellRHeight = Cell.Offset(1)
        End If
        LR = target_sheet.Range("B" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row + 1
        If Cell.value = "End Date" Then
            source_sheet.Range(Cell.Offset(, 1), Cell.Offset(, 3)).Copy
            Set rngTr = target_sheet.Range("B" & LR)
            rngTr.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlAll, Transpose:=True
        End If
    Next
    ReDim Preserve arrPAddr(1 To 2, 1 To k - 1)
    'Making the row height in target_sheet equal to source_sheet column with:
    target_sheet.Range("2:" & LR + 3).EntireRow.RowHeight = source_sheet.Range("A16").EntireRow.RowHeight
    target_sheet.Range("A:C").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    target_sheet.Range("C1").EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = cellRHeight.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth
    'copy paste image:
    Dim i As Long
    For Each pic In source_sheet.Shapes
        For i = 1 To UBound(arrPAddr, 2)
            If pic.TopLeftCell.Address = arrPAddr(1, i) Then
                pic.Copy: target_sheet.Paste
                With target_sheet.Shapes(target_sheet.Shapes.count)
                    .top = target_sheet.Range(arrPAddr(2, i)).top + (target_sheet.Range(arrPAddr(2, i)).RowHeight - pic.height) / 2
                    .left = target_sheet.Range(arrPAddr(2, i)).left
                End With
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    Next

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 target_sheet.Activate
 MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

Plese, test the code and send some feedback

Comment: FaneDuru thanks a lot for this code. Name and Date are ok however I don't see any pictures in column C

Comment: I am driving... have the pictures been copied? Even if in different places... i tested tge code and it workrd

Comment: unfortunately no, I have no pictures on target_sheet, only name and date. I just realized that images  are sometimes placed not in the end but after the name row so data is structured like that: Name, Image, Price, Link etc. I also check picture file extension and these are .png files

Comment: But, this does not match the image pattern from your question. Wgwn i will be at home I will try dealunf wuth this situation. But I would like you to edit your question an better explain the source sheet structure.

Comment: I just added new screenshot of input (source) sheet and expeced output

Comment: So, the former "Name" becomes "Product Name", "Date" becomes "End Date" and the three products will become 2 and the row keeping the pictures is the one below "Product Name" row. Is this understanding correct? I would not like to waste my time for something not covered by your real scenario...

Comment: thanks a lot FaneDuru, what if I have 3 or 5 pictures? Does the number of pictures needs to be fixed? What if I had info on how many images are in the row and your macro would take that number? Let's say that the column with number of images would be column Z.

Comment: @Adrian: I am afraid yes, with the philosophy of the above code. You must remember that you placed a question asking for a solution, then modifying it completely in terms of patterns. Everything can be done, but we here only answer the questions as they are and help people understand their mistakes and learn. **Does my above code answer your question as it is (became)**? If yes, you have to place another question with the new request, showing the existing code. If you tag me and I am available, I will try adapting the code. If not, somebody else will do it...

Comment: @Adrian: And, if it answered your question, we here vote the answer up and most important, tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. Our main goal here is to make people learning. If somebody else will search for a similar issue, he will know that the code works...

Comment: FaneDuru, I am afraid that the limitation to 2 or 3 pictures makes this code useless for me and for other users. I didn't mention that I want that kind of limitation and I showed you first 2 products as and example. In the first code presented by you you didn't put anything like that so I thought that this will not change.

Comment: @Adrian: Look at your question, please, and mention where you said something about the variable number of shapes. You only placed two pictures with the existing pattern and what you need. Only three pictures per row were involved. Then you tried my code on  different pattern and, of course, it couldn't work. I asked you to edit the question with your existing pattern and you placed it containing two pictures. I adapted my code to process different key words, rows placement and number of pictures from the two presented patterns. I explained in a comment what is to be done and then made the code

Comment: FaneDuru, thank you very much for your time and solution. Apologies for inconvenience

Comment: @Adrian: No problem with me. Try posting a new question, using my code and try (better) explaining the context and what you need. If you tag me (here) or wherever, if I will be available I will try helping. If not, somebody else will show you how to deal with it.